# Glitchy Animation on jquery menu script

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, mouseleave

So i have a menu botton on top of the page and it do a little hover animation with css :hover.

```
$('.menu_button').click(function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: '-=50'
                }, 250);
                $('nav').delay(250).animate({
                    top: '+=50'
                }, 250);
                $('nav').mouseleave(function () {
                    $(this).delay(750).animate({
                        top: '-=50'
                    }, 250);
                    $('.menu_button').delay(1000).animate({
                        top: '+=50'
                    }, 250);
                });
            });
```

On click the menu button slides up and the menu slides down like in the fiddle.
On mouseleave the animation goes on the other way around after 750ms.

But if you play around 2 or 3 times the menu button slides far more down than the original position. Sometimes it disappears out of the top. Cant say why and when this happens. I can replicate the glitch when i didnt click the  but right above the top in the inside of the div.

Any idea or suggestion whats wrong?

**The fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/c5D22/

regards
dennym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the nav animation into an anonymous callback function and set the `top` property to absolute values with px units:

```
$('.menu_button').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-50px'
    }, 250, function () {
        $('nav').animate({
            top: '50px'
        }, 250);
    });
});

$('nav').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).delay(750).animate({
        top: '-50px'
    }, 250);
    $('.menu_button').delay(1000).animate({
        top: '-10px'
    }, 250);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c5D22/4/

Comment: after 2 or 3 times it only fires off if the mosue is moved. If u click and dont move the mouse its stuck somehow.

Comment: yeah thats seems to work, fixed some px values for my purpose. thanks you sir